# namedpipe pingpong syncronizate processes

Tags: c, process, named-pipes

I have to synchronize 2 processes with the Named Pipe. The father has to print n times "Ping" and after he send "C" to his son that prints "Pong". After the las "ping" the father send "Q" and the son prints the last "Pong" and leave terminating himself. It's working but sometime the last pong is not printed.

```
void pingpong(int n)
{
    char buffer;
    pid_t pid;
    mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP;
    int descEcriture, descLecture;
    if ( mkfifo(("père"), mode) < 0 ){
        perror("mkfifo");
    } 
    if ( mkfifo(("fils"), mode) < 0 ){
        perror("mkfifo");
    }  
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0){
        perror("fork");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if(pid == 0){
        while(1){


            if((descEcriture = open("père", O_WRONLY)) < 0){
                perror("père  Tube");
                exit(-1);
            }
            if(n == 0){
                write(descEcriture, "Q", 1);
                break;
            }
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Ping", strlen("Ping")+1);
            write(descEcriture, "C", 1);
            close(descEcriture);
            if((descLecture = open("fils", O_RDONLY))<0){
                perror("père  Tube");
                exit(-1);
            }
            read(descLecture, &buffer, 1);
            close(descLecture);
            n--;
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        while(1){
            if((descLecture = open("père", O_RDONLY)) < 0){
                perror("pere Tube");
                exit(-1);
            }
            read(descLecture, &buffer, 1);
            if (buffer == 'C')
            {
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Pong", strlen("Pong")+1);
            }
            if (buffer=='Q')
            {
                break;
            }
            if((descEcriture = open("fils", O_WRONLY)) < 0){
                perror("fils Tube");
                exit(-1);
            }
            write(descEcriture, "K", 1);
        }
        unlink("père"); unlink("fils");
        exit(0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to open and close the pipes every iteration of the loops. Try opening the pipes before the loops and closing them after.

Also, you are printing the null byte after the strings "ping" and "pong" since you're adding 1 to the return value of strlen. Try something like this:

```
// Near top of program:
#define PING "ping"
#define PONG " : pong\n"

// In pingpong function:
        // In parent:
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, PING, strlen(PING));
        // In child:
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, PONG, strlen(PONG));
```

And you seem to have parent and child mixed up. If pid is 0, it's the child, not the parent.